# Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.decorator.AndroidPluginDslDecoratorKt

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\project_app\flutter_application_1\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.decorator.AndroidPluginDslDecoratorKt

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

After spending time I finally got solutions for this problem.

Step 1:
Update dependencies in build.gradle to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2
```

Step 2: Update URL in gradle-wrapper.properties file distributionUrl

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/**gradle-7.5-all.zip
```